# How can I use jQuery to prevent a user from typing too many decimal places?

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to write a jQuery plugin to prevent users from typing numbers with more than 2 decimal places. Specifically:

- If an input contains `12` and the user types `3` at the end, it should work.
- If an input contains `12.34` and the user types `1` at the end, **nothing should happen**.
- If an input contains `12.34` and the user types `1` at the beginning, it should work.

Here's the problem I'm running into:

- If I bind to `keypress`, I do not know what the "proposed new value" is; `$(this).val()` is the value before the user pressed the key, and I don't know where in the input field the user is typing.
- If I bind to `keyup`, `$(this).val()` is the new value, but it has already appeared in the text input. I can erase it if it has too many decimal places, but it looks glitchy.

How can I do this?

Comment: Did you try `onkeydown`?

Comment: @Ryan - Yes, but I could not tell that `keydown` was any different from `keypress` in this respect. If I hold down a key, `keydown` continues to fire but `keypress` only fires once; that's all I can see that's different.

Comment: Would this be acceptable? http://jsfiddle.net/vdZfH/1/

Comment: @ŠimeVidas - it let's me type `12.34` and hold down `5`; only when I let go do the `5`s disappear. Also I can type `12.34.56.....7`

Comment: @NathanLong That's because the handler triggered on keyup - that's why I asked if the demo is acceptable. Regarding the two dots, the demo does not prevent you from entering non-numeric values. For instance, you can also type `ABC...`. In your question you wrote "*prevent users from typing numbers...*". You did not state that entering non-numeric values should also be prevented.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Mebbe this?

```
jQuery.fn.limitDecimalPlaces = function(maxPlaces) {
  $(this).on('keyup', function(e) {
    integer = e.target.value.split('.')[0],
    mantissa = e.target.value.split('.')[1];

    if (typeof mantissa === 'undefined') {
      mantissa = '';
    }

    if (mantissa.length > maxPlaces) {
      e.target.value = integer + '.' + mantissa.substring(0, maxPlaces);
    }
  });
}
```

Tested and working at http://jsfiddle.net/vdZfH/2/

Comment: What happens if you have `23.45` and the user types `1` at the beginning?

Comment: Nothing unusual. Using a `maxPlaces` of 2 as an example, the decimal is still two digits away from the end of the string, so the user is allowed to add the 1 to the beginning of the string. Adding it to the end, would fail as that moves the decimal place more than `maxPlaces` away from the end of the string.

Comment: Testing here - http://jsfiddle.net/vdZfH/1/ - I'm able to enter 3 decimal places when I specified 2, and once I've done so, I can't add anything left of the decimal until I erase a character right of it.

Comment: Pete - hope you don't mind my edit; I combined your plugin and your updated code. Accepting your answer because it's simpler than mine. There are a couple of drawbacks: 1) additional decimal places appear momentarily before being erased 2) if I have `12.45` and enter `3` right after the decimal, the `5` is erased (not the `3`). I think these are OK tradeoffs for the simplicity, though, and probably a better general-case solution than mine.

Comment: Also, thanks for teaching me the word 'mantissa'. I just want to say it over and over. "Mantissa. Man... tissa." :)

Comment: Hi, I just had a look at improving this answer by using keypress, so output would not be displayed then deleted.  It was looking real complicated, which makes me appreciate @NathanLong's answer more.

Answer (score 2):

### Solution that works for my purposes

Here's what I came up with.

#### Pros

- Excessive decimal places do not appear at all (as opposed to appearing and being immediately erased)
- User also cannot enter multiple decimals

#### Cons

This solution depends on 2 other jQuery plugins in this, but I already had them in my project anyway.

- I'm using the `caret()` function that's part of `jQuery.maskedInput` to determine where in the input box the user is typing.
- I'm already using `jQuery.keyfilter` on this input to ensure that only `1-9` and `.` are allowed to be typed in it. (It only considers individual keystrokes, though, not the resulting input contents.)

#### The code

```
jQuery.fn.limitDecimalPlaces = function (maxPlacesArg) {
  $(this).each(function() {
    var maxPlaces, presetValue;

    if (maxPlacesArg) {
      maxPlaces = maxPlacesArg;

    } else {
      presetValue = $(this).attr('value');

      // If the value attribute has a decimal in it...
      if (presetValue.indexOf('.') !== -1) {

        // ... assume it has the correct number of places
        maxPlaces = presetValue.split('.')[1].length;
      } else {

        // Sensible default
        maxPlaces = 2;
      }
    }
    $(this).bind("keypress", function(e) {
      var currentVal, cursorIsAfterDecimal, hasMaxDecimalPlaces, inputHasDecimal, keystrokeIsDecimal;
      currentVal = $(this).val();
      inputHasDecimal = currentVal.indexOf('.') !== -1;
      if (inputHasDecimal) {
        // Booleans
        keystrokeIsDecimal = String.fromCharCode(e.which) === '.';
        hasMaxDecimalPlaces = athena.format.hasNDecimalPlaces(currentVal, maxPlaces);
        cursorIsAfterDecimal = ($(this).caret().begin) > (currentVal.lastIndexOf('.'));

        if (keystrokeIsDecimal || (hasMaxDecimalPlaces && cursorIsAfterDecimal)) {
          e.preventDefault();
        }
      }
    });
  });
  return $(this);
}
```

The supporting function:

```
hasNDecimalPlaces = function (number, places) {
  fixed = parseFloat(number).toFixed(places);
  return number.toString() === fixed;
};
```